# django tastypie error "no such table"

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a Django project which is using tastypie.
When I try delete a row from auth_user as following:

```
user.delete()
```

It raises a error as

```
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'develop.tastypie_apikey' doesn't exist")
```

I search for a while and know that there is a chance this will happen when you create a new row, but I am trying to delete.

Does any one know what probably could be wrong at this point?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

If you use south-migration run this command from command line:

```
django-admin.py migrate tastypie
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! My problem is an another issue which is solved by a different way.

Answer (score 2):

The tastypie application has its own set of database tables, one of which is `tastypie_apikey`.  This requires that when you add `tastypie` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` variable that syncdb is run.

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

This will introspect your database and create any missing tables.

Comment: thanks for the answer! My problem is an another issue which is solved by a different way.

Comment: @FanyongMeng Glad you solved it.  It's ok to answer your own question.  Perhaps you could leave an answer so that others coming along later will find your solution.

Comment: The thing is that it has nothing to do with tastypie, I made a mistake at another place. So probably it is not useful for the people who really have this problem.